# Pillow does not generate the right image when converting items from numpy array to jpg/bmp

Tags: image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert the Numpy array items to images from the PEER-Hub ImageNet so that I can reclassify them for my own use case. However, Pillow produces images with random green purple and blue pixels that vaguely resemble the images of buildings.

I tried directly converting the array items to images but Pillow cannot read images with float values for an RGB image. So I had to convert them first to of type uint8.

```
for i in range(len(data)-1220):
    im = Image.fromarray((data[i]).astype(np.uint8))
    fname = '%05d_p%s.jpg' % (i, y[i])
    path = "/mnt/c/Windows/System32/repos/thesis_raw_data/task5/photos/"
    im.save(f"{path}{fname}")
```

However, the code produces something like the image below.

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with the conversion of the `dtype` but you need to worry about both the `dtype` *and* the range.

Let's look at a Numpy array of floats and its conversion to `uint8`:

```
im = np.array([10.3, 200.5, 254.3, 255.5, 256.7, 257.3, 258.4, 400.1])

print(im.astype(np.uint8))
```

and that yields:

```
array([ 10, 200, 254, 255,   0,   1,   2, 144], dtype=uint8)
```

As you can see, you got the `dtype` you were hoping for but the magnitude of the values goes wrong when 255 is exceeded.

So, we need to consider also the range of your values. Without any *a priori* knowledge, your floats will be in the range `-sys.float_info.max` to  `sys.float_info.max`, or -1.7976931348623157e+308 to 1.7976931348623157e+308. We need to map that rather large range onto the range 0..255. One way to do this is get the minimum float in your image and map that to 0, and then map the maximum value to 255 with all other values in between mapped linearly.

So, as you already have Numpy arrays, you can do:

```
scaled = 255 * (im - im.min())/(im.max() - im.min())
```

Then you can use:

```
pilImage = Image.fromarray(scaled.astype(np.uint8))
```

---

Let's generate a test image with floating point values in the range 1000..2000:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Set height and width
w, h = 640, 480

# Synthesise image with pixels between 1000..2000
im = np.linspace(1000,2000, h*w).reshape((h,w))

# Now scale to range 0..255 and make uint8 per answer above
scaled = 255 * (im - im.min())/(im.max() - im.min())

pilImage = Image.fromarray(scaled.astype(np.uint8))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Not only did you solve my problem, you taught me what the problem was and why it occurs. I hope I get to be as knowledgeable and concise as you in the future!!